# How to save ListBoxFor Values to database in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to save all listBoxFor values to the Database... when posting the form i have this error saying Object not Set to an Instant of an Object, Can anyone help me to figure out what the problem is?

This is all the code

This is the listbox code that contain all the values:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRecipientId, new MultiSelectList(Model.Recipients, "ID", "RecipientNumbers"), new { id = "recipientList", style = "width: 250px; height: 160px;", name = "recipientList" })
```

This is my View model

```
public class SendViewModel
{
    public SendViewModel()
    {
        ScheduledDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Times { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedRecipientId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model that I am trying to write to

```
public class SentMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime SendDate { get; set; }
    public int RecipientCount { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<MessageRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Post Controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (model.ScheduledDate == DateTime.Now)
    {
        _messageService.SendMessage(User, SenderId, model.Message, model.SelectedRecipientId);

        return Redirect("/UserAccount/SendMessageConfirmation");
    }
}
```

And lastly this is the message service parameter collection

```
int SendMessage(int userId, string senderId, string message, IEnumerable<string> recipients);
```

This is the Signature that save all the data from the view to the database and the `IEnumerable<string> recipients` is the parameter responsibl for getting all the values from the listbox.

How do I go about it so that it will be able to save to the database.

This is the Error stack Trace

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 68:                         
Line 69:                             **Recipients** 
Line 70:                             @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRecipientId, new MultiSelectList(Model.Recipients, "ID", "RecipientNumbers"), new { id = "recipientList", style = "width: 250px; height: 160px;", name = "SelectedRecipientId" })
Line 71:                             
Line 72:

Source File: c:\Development\Projects\SMSXChange\SmsXchange\XChange.MVC\Views\Message\Send.cshtml    Line: 70

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Message_Send_cshtml

Comment: You are setting name of your Select control to **recipientList** and then you are trying to access **model.SelectedRecipientId** .. How it is going to work? Element name should match to property name of model class

Comment: Please Is that the reason?

Comment: Yeah you can change it and check the output

Comment: I Changed the Name and am still having this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: can you explain on which line you are getting an error exactly? Please add the exception stack trace to the post to have a look to it

Comment: This is where the error is pointing to @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRecipientId, new MultiSelectList(Model.Recipients, "ID", "RecipientNumbers"), new { id = "recipientList", style = "width: 250px; height: 160px;", name = "recipientList" })

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the error details,

Although the thing i mentioned in my comment is correct that both "`HTML Element Name`" and "`Model Property Name`" should be similar to post the value but here the problem is something different for the error you are getting.

Make sure that you are filling your Model.Recipients property correctly before rendering the view. Your action from where you are calling the view should assign correct value for `Model.Recipients` property. Your property is null hence it is throwing an object reference error.

In fact the error should come on initial load of the form and not after posting it.
If still it is coming after posting the form then there is following possibility.
As you have added `ModelState.IsValid` check it seems this is not getting satisfied and there is some validation error which is causing the Post action method to render same view again (Provider you have are not doing anything else in else part) and when the view gets loaded again it doesn't have the select list filled as you haven't added that code in post method. Hence the possible solution would be to fill the `Model.Recipients` again on POST action if there is any validation error. I hope you got my point

Comment: Yes That's true and In fact that's were i am having issues so please how do i instantiate it to my recipient model so that when i add recipient to the listbox then it will get the listbox values and when posting to the database... this is my Recipient Model :::::::::


public class MessageRecipient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public SentMessage Message { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public MessageStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Where am confuse is that, I am not pulling any data from database to to the listbox. Am only adding the content to the listbox in the view and then send it to the database... why will i need the instantiation in the GetAction??

Comment: Well the way you are writing **@Html.ListBoxFor** and supplying the select list object, you have to instantiate it

Comment: Okay, Please do I do That?... when am debugging iI find out that the listbox return null on post, how do I assign it please Help.